# Number of Executors is less than what is assigned for a Spark job

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-manager

I am having two hadoop clusters containing 15(big) and 3(small) nodes respectively. Both are managed by cloudera manager. I am running a Spark job using yarn setting --num-executors to 6. The Spark UI of the big cluster is showing the 6 executors, but Spark UI of the small cluster is showing only 3 executors. What are the probable reasons for it? And also how to overcome the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont have enough memory on the cluster for the number of executors you have requested you will get less. How much memory is on the 3 small nodes and how much are you asking for per executor?

Comment: @JemTucker 64 GB on three small nodes and I am asking for 30GB per executor.

Comment: And what about the number of cores ?

Comment: When you request memory through spark submit an overhead is added, it is probably that with this overhead there is not enough memory for more than one executor